# Split listings with jagged edges

Tags: listings

so my english isn't the best and therefor i have problems to google my problem correctly. so maybe someone here can help me.

I draw a picture for you with paint, so you can understand what i'm looking for.

[image: Listing]

so i want to have two or more listings which are kinda connected like in the image, so the reader knows that that's not the whole code he is seeing

Answer (score 1):

Use `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% ridiculously small page for illustration only
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,listings,skins}
\begin{document}
\tcbinputlisting{enhanced jigsaw,breakable,listing only,listing file=knuth.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]